# How do I get count of records from previous day in SQL, Bigquery?

Tags: sql, time, google-bigquery

As written in the question, I'm trying to get a count of all records from the previous day in Bigquery. My column for the times is ingest_time. I've tried the query below, but it doesn't work in Bigquery. I'm using standard sql in bigquery for this question.

```
where 
  date(ingest_time)=date(date_sub(now(),interval 1 day));
```

Comment: Are you using standard or legacy SQL with BigQuery?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following for standard SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM yourTable
WHERE DATE(ingest_time) >= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to Tim's answer, you can use COUNTIF operator:

```
select 
  COUNTIF(DATE(ingest_time) >= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)) as cnt 
FROM yourTable
```